# C ARM programming

Tags: c, arm

I had two questions regarding writing into registers for ARM programming using C language.

1st: I'm trying to write to the Application Interrupt and Reset Control Register or AIRCR. It's a 32-bit register. I need two write 0x5FA values at bits 16 to 31 (the need of register). I also need to modify some other bits, but singularly. I meant, only bitwise (0 or 1). I know how to do this when it's only a bit. using  `*iser0 |= 0UL << 2`; for example. But my question is that how can I write to a part of the register, namely, the AIRCR[31:16] while being able to manipulate other bits.

2nd: This issue is not my main issue, But when I compile my C program, It's return value is not 0. Is this abnormal? What has been my mistake?

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;

int main()
{
    //Multi drive register
    uint32_t* muer=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E50UL;
    *muer |= 1UL << 8;

    uint32_t* mudr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E54UL;
    *mudr |= 0UL << 8;

    //Pio controller register
    uint32_t* per=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E00UL;
    *per |= 1UL << 8;

    uint32_t* pdr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E04UL;
    *pdr |= 0UL << 8;

    //output register
    uint32_t* oer=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E10UL;
    *oer |= 0UL << 8;

    uint32_t* odr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E14UL;
    *odr |= 1UL << 8;

    //edge select
    uint32_t* esr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0EC0;
    *esr |= 1UL << 8;

    //level select
    uint32_t* lsr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0EC4;
    *lsr |= 0UL << 8;

    //Rising edge
    uint32_t* rehlsr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0ED4;
    *rehlsr |= 1UL << 8;

    //Falling edge edge
    uint32_t* fellsr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0ED8;
    *fellsr |= 0UL << 8;

    //Interrupt set-enable register
    uint32_t* iser0=(uint32_t*) 0xE000E100;
    *iser0 |= 1UL << 11;

    //Interrupt clear-enable register
    uint32_t* icer0=(uint32_t*) 0xE000E180;
    *icer0 |= 0UL << 11;

    //AIRCR
    uint32_t* aircr=(uint32_t*) 0xFA050000;

    //VECTKEY
    *aircr |= 0x5FA << 16;

    //ENDIANESS
    *iser0 |= 0UL << 15;

    //PRIGRIOUP
    *iser0 |= 5UL << 8;

    //SYSRESETREQ
    *iser0 |= 0UL << 2;

    //VECTCLRACTIVE
    *iser0 |= 0UL << 1;

    //SYSRESETREQ
    *iser0 |= 0UL;
}
```

This is my code.

**Update:**
I understood that I cannot do |= 0UL, instead, I should use &= 1 << bits.
I tried this one for my other code. But it still doesn't return 0, and surprisingly, it takes 10 seconds to compile.

```
#include<stdint.h>


int main()
{

//Pull up register
volatile uint32_t* puer=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E64UL;
*puer &= 1 << 8;


volatile uint32_t* pudr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E60UL;
*pudr |= 1UL << 8;


//Multi drive register
volatile uint32_t* muer=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E50UL;
*muer &= 1 << 8;

volatile uint32_t* mudr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E54UL;
*mudr |= 1UL << 8;

//Pio controller register
volatile uint32_t* per=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E00UL;
*per |= 1UL << 8;

volatile uint32_t* pdr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E04UL;
*pdr &= 1 << 8;


//ABSR register
volatile uint32_t* absr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E70UL;
*absr &= 1 << 8;

//output register
volatile uint32_t* oer=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E10UL;
*oer |= 1UL << 8;

volatile uint32_t* odr=(uint32_t*) 0x400E0E14UL;
*odr &= 1 << 8;

}
```

**Update**
I have not connected my micro to my PC. One possible issue is that I don't have these addresses on my machine?

Comment: `int32_t` is defined by `stdint.h`, your typedef is either redundant or illegal

Comment: try either doing `return 0;` at the end of main, or compiling in C99 mode

Comment: I wonder about the cases where you're doing something like `*iser0 |= 0UL << 15`. Since 0 shifted left by any number of bits is still going be zero, and any value OR'd with zero is going to be the original value, this seems to be a no-op as far as I can tell. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Typically, the minimum signature for a `C` `main()` function is `int main(void){...return 0;}`, or more common `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){...return 0};`

Comment: To set a bit: `*register |= 1 << bit`, to clear a bit: `*register &= ~(1 << bit)`

Comment: You could also define your registers in terms of bitfields, which would then allow you to do things like `(*register).xyz = true` or `(*register).whatever = 723`. This way you would avoid having to do all the bit manipulation by hand.

Comment: @M.M return 0 didn't work I forgot to mention
And yes that part is redundant. I was trying to use typedef but left it and forgot to delete it

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I was trying to set 15th bit to zero. I had read this that with shifting you can do so. But I'm not sure. My original question is that suppose you want to modify a 32-bit register at a given address. You want to modify a chunk of bits that are adjacent together but scattered in total 32 places. For example, one chunk might be only one bit, as the 15th bit, and another might be more than one bit.

Comment: @ryyker I tried adding return 0 but it didn't work. About passing arguments to main, As I recall it is not necessary?

Comment: `int main()` or `int main(void)` are indeed valid, you don't need to specify arguments (the int return type is mandatory though)

Comment: @FelixG what do you mean by .whatever? In my code, I want to write 0x5FA in 16th bit to 31st bit and several 1-bit assignments (like bits 0,1,2 and 15) and another 3-bit assignment in 8 and 9 and 10th slot altogether.
Does shifting alone works? I mean if I try to change the ith bit by | and <<, operators, would it also ruin my previous assignments to previous bits?
I'd prefer to be able to assign in hex number if possible because doing it bit by bit is tedious.

Comment: I don't know the layout of your registers, so .whatever is a placeholder for any name that makes sense for your particular register. Check out my answer for a slightly more complete example (but again with placeholders)

Comment: What ARM is this? If it's a bare metal one, then it's senseless to return anything from main().

Comment: All those pointers and casts must be `volatile` qualified.

Comment: If you want to set the 15th bit to zero you need to do something like `*iser0 &= ~(1UL << 15)`. `1UL << 15` gives you 0x00008000. Complementing this using the `~` operator gives you 0xFFFF7FFF. ANDing this with whatever `iser` points to means that all the bits in `*iser` are preserved *except* for the one bit that is cleared in `0xFFFF7FFF`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Felix G: Would you have an answer to Lundin's question, i.e. what is the Arm processor you are targeting? This would help helping you.

Comment: @Frant you should probably ask m0ss, since they're the one who asked the question ;-) (if i had to guess though, i'd assume bare-metal, since you usually don't access CPU registers in a hosted environment)

Comment: @Felix G - my mistake. Agree for the bare-metal, and from the PIO/AIRCR  addresses, I would speculate  his target is an Atmel SAM3S Cortex-M3, but this is a long shot.

Comment: @Frant yes you are right about my intended processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to clear a single bit of a variable, you don't use `*register |= 0 << bit` but instead `*register &= ~(1 << bit)`. If you want to manipulate more than one bit, essentially what you have to do is erase the relevant part and then overwrite it with your desired pattern.

This for example will delete the bits 4 to 6, and then overwrite them with the contents of `value`:

```
*register &= 0x7 << 4
*register |= (value & 0x7) << 4;
```

As for your second question:
Never ever try to run code that tries to access random memory locations like that on a PC. This is something you only do to access registers on a microcontroller. Your PC doesn't have those registers and even if it did, your operating system hides the actual physical memory from you anyway.

**DISCLAIMER:**

As pointed out by Lundin, using bitfields is compiler/architecture-dependent and therefore non-portable. If you want to use them, you will have to check your compiler's documentation to make sure they work as expected. When in doubt, prefer the solution above. Continue reading at your own risk ;-)

With that out of the way, what you could also do, in order to avoid the bit manipulation is something like this:

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t vectreset     :1;
        uint32_t vectclractive :1;
        uint32_t sysresetreq   :1;
        uint32_t               :5;
        uint32_t prigroup      :3;
        uint32_t               :4;
        uint32_t endianness    :1;
        uint32_t vectkey       :0;
    };
    uint32_t u32;
} *aircr = (void*)0xFA050000;
```

And then in your code, access the bitfield like this: `(*aircr).vectkey = 0x5FA;`

Comment: I did it in another program which I only need to modify several bits, not more than one bit at any register.
Again, the return value is 3221225477 and it takes 10 seconds for my program to terminate, although it's only 20-30 lines.
Is it possible that it happens because I have not connected my Micro to my PC? because at this time I don't have access to my micro and I'm just coding.

Comment: By the way, when you are making your struct, why some uing32_t doesn't have any name?
I had not ever encountered this. I'm new to Microcontroller programming. Is there any document that I can read to understand these structs and how they relate to bit manipulation? Before this, I could only work with structs in order to mimic object-oriented programming

Comment: No, bit-wise operators is the correct way to do this. Using bit-fields is always wrong, for any purpose, since they are extremly poorly defined in the C language.

Comment: @user694733 oops, typo ^^

Comment: I did not see any usage of `volatile` in the code, it shall be used when reading/writing  registers - see [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409545/using-volatile-in-embedded-c-development) and this [Arm utility header file](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/include/lib/mmio.h).

Comment: Look at my update, please. I attached my other code.

Comment: @Lundin I don't say that bitfields are the best option here (and my first example was how to do it without them), but they are of course defined in section 6.7.2.1 of the C standard. Whether that definition is sufficient or not is up to debate i guess.

Comment: @Frant I Also added volatile to all my uint32s. But still no return 0 and 5 seconds running time. Is this normal?
Again I should note that at this time I'm just coding and my micro is not connected to my PC, So maybe these addresses don't exist on my system?

Comment: @Lundin You think I should do it bit by bit? But stil no return 0, as I mentioned in my update and added volatile to all my uint32's

Comment: @m0ss You can't just run code that's meant for a µC on your computer like that. Those addresses are registers specific to the microcontroller you are using, they aren't valid on your PC

Comment: @m0ss You don't need to do it bit-by-bit, see the very first example in my answer: delete a section of bits, then overwrite that section with your value.

Comment: @FelixG Is there any way I'm able to see I've done it right?
Maybe declare another valid address on my PC, assign the same values to it and check it?

Comment: @Lundin point taken. I will add a disclaimer to my answer, that the use of bitfields is non-portable and not the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: @m0ss yes, that would be an option. Just do the bit manipulation on some local variable instead of random addresses which may or may not exist.

Comment: @m0ss also, if you want your code to return 0, you should just add a `return 0;` to the end of `main()`

Comment: @FelixG I checked to add return 0, but it didn't work. Have you checked it on your system?
I also was busy with another task so I'll check my first part of my question ASAP.

Comment: touching the address using two lines will change the state twice, better to use an intermediate value and only change it once.   bitfields are just bad.  improper use of unions like this is even worse avoid using that at all costs, bit manipulation in C is trivial and you can get the compiler to produce equivalent code without venturing off into implementation defined solutions.  Use the first solution with an intermediate value temp=register.  temp &=,   temp |=,  register = temp.

Comment: a fair amount of baremetal is operating at this level so the primary way you know you did it right is by reading your code and comparing it to the reference manual.  you could in some way inspect the register after, debugger, printing in some way (that doesnt add a massive library) blinking an led in a pattern representing the bits read from a register, something.  but you would then need to do that for everything and that would take a while.  so have to build the confidence and accuracy in the code, occasionally examine the disassembly or regularly if using bitfield/union solutions.

Comment: @FelixG I tried adding a printf("%s","Hello") In my code, but it didn't even say hello! Do you know why my codes behave like that?
I was going to check if I'm doing it the right way, just declare another dummy address. But it didn't work. Didn't print anything.
By the way, do you know what address range I should try? for my dummy register?